# Add "Host" to the Headers, getting an error (HTTPWebRequest)

Tags: c#

I must use this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Headers.Add("Host", "gs.apple.com");
response = request.GetResponse();
```

But I get an error.
"This header must be modified using the appropriate property."

I googled a lot and found, that I should use a property or the HTTPWebRequest.
But there is no Host-Property.

I need to manipulate it, how I can do it?

(C#.Net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN says:

```
Host

Set by the system to current host information.
```

If you want to modify it try:

```
request.Headers["Host"] = "gs.apple.com";
```

or

```
request.Host = "gs.apple.com";
```

The appropriate property is [HttpWebRequest.Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.host.aspx)

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)